# Linq error in c# windows forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, datagridview

Hello I'm having trouble figuring out this error in c# windows forms application , I'm trying to make a search box to search through database and display it on DataGridView, all is fine until I want to search with keyPress on textbox.

This is my current code:

```
using MetroFramework.Forms;
using System;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Ruby_Malli
{
    public partial class Form : MetroForm
    {
        MalliEntities test;

        public MalliEntities Test { get => test; set => test = value; }


        public Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel.Enabled = false;
            Test = new MalliEntities();
            malliBindingSource.DataSource = test.mallis.ToList();
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
               malliBindingSource.EndEdit();
                test.SaveChangesAsync();
                panel.Enabled = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                malliBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);

            }
        }

        private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                panel.Enabled = true;
                txtID.Focus();
                malli c = new malli();
                test.mallis.Add(c);
                malliBindingSource.Add(c);
                malliBindingSource.MoveLast();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel.Enabled = true;
            txtID.Focus();
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel.Enabled = false;
            malliBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
            foreach (DbEntityEntry entry in test.ChangeTracker.Entries()) 
            {
                switch (entry.State)
                {
                    case System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added:
                        entry.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached;
                        break;
                    case System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified:
                        entry.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
                        break;
                    case System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted:
                        entry.Reload();
                        break;
                }

            }
        }

        private void txtKerko_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyChar == (char)13)
            {
                if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtKerko.Text))
                {
                    dataGridView.DataSource = malliBindingSource;
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[This is my design in form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Vuqe.png)

[And this is the error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/si7ov.png)

Error text:
**System.InvalidOperationException: 'The specified cast from a materialized 'System.String' type to the 'System.Int16' type is not valid.'**

[My database is simple as this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMk2p.png)

Comment: change the datatype of the id to int

Comment: @Sajeetharan I did,still the same.

Comment: what is the output?

Comment: @Sajeetharan System.InvalidOperationException: 'The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.Int16' type is not valid.'

Comment: same error now also?

Comment: @Sajeetharan No now I get systemint32 to 16 is not valid,before I got string

Comment: @Sajeetharan beware! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311869/should-we-allow-people-to-offer-help-via-outside-communications-like-teamviewer/311917

Comment: @Steve my intention was to help anyway

Comment: @Sajeetharan I am absolutely sure of your good intentions. But still it is not a recommended practice to use these tools to help. It is just an advice, no police here.

Comment: @Steve Ok noted, thanks for the link